# makecert - create a certificate with issuer name

Tags: c#, x509certificate, makecert

I am trying to create a certificate using the MakeCert so that the "Issued By Name" and "Issued To Name" show up in the "Issued by" column and "Issued To" columns respectively in the certificate manager.

```
makecert -ss My -n "CN=Issued By Name" -cy authority -in "Issued To Name" Test.cer
```

The "Issued By Name" specified above does not show up in the "Issued By" column in the certificate manager. Instead the default value "Root agency" shows up and I can not find the expected certificates using the following code.

```
X509Certificate2Collection certificates = null;
certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "Issued By Name", false);
```

Can somebody help here?

Comment: Perhaps you also need to include -ic, -iv, or similar arguments.

Comment: From *[MakeCert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*, option "-in": *"...  for certificate store technology only ... -in IssuerNameString ... Description: Common name of the issuer's certificate. MakeCert will search in the certificate store for a certificate whose common name includes IssuerNameString."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Which would mean that creating a certificate in this fashion would likely need to be done on the machine that the Certificate: "the Certificate Store Certificate", is installed on or this would fail. Helpful post, Thumbs up thanks!